# Accessing android app through TCP/IP by PC connected to android hotspot

Tags: java, android, modbus, hotspot, modbus-tcp

I'm creating an Android app which is Mod-Bus TCP slave simulator and I have a problem when trying to connect from pc to it while sharing a connection via wifi hotspot.

I tried using gateway IP but it does not work. When phone and pc are connected to the same wifi (other than themselves) everything is working fine but I need to make it also work with hotspot running and pc connected to it. Is it possible? How?

App is using modbus4j lib.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Use static IP address "192.168.43.1" in case of hotspot connection.

Comment: @I2ufu5 did you try above solution?

Comment: It does work now. 
But when i tried it before it didn't, maybe because something was bugged and used the port that i'm using for the connecitvity.

Anyway. THANKS for replies :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't think so that Modbus TCP works on mobile hotspot too because recently when i was working on MB TCP I found this. I tried to connect with the ip and gateway of my mobile hotspot but it didn't work this could happen because our mobile hotspot works on DHCP  so the gateway is not static. But Modbus TCP works very fine on Wifi router ip and gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with java or android or Modbus, but it is a problem of understanding how routing works on the internet and on internal networks (your WiFi network is an internal network)

The problem is that the ports waiting for connections on the internal network, like your android device, are not accessible from the internet.

To make them accessible, one or more NAT rules must be defined in the WiFi router. But this will only work if your internet provider assigns you a public IP, which is less and less frequent due to the shortage of public IPs.